# Python NameError for methods defined later in a module

Tags: python

Why does python require you to define methods before you use them in the same module

e.g.

```
def a():
  b()
def b():
  ...
```

Doesn't work because b() is defined after a(), which calls b() within its body

Comment: Python requires no such thing. Either your impression is wrong or your code sample incomplete.

Answer (score 7):

Code like this should work, unless you have a call of `a()` between the `def a()` and the `def b()` part, because in that case `a()` would be executed, trying to execute `b()`, which is not defined yet at that point of time.